# Re-arrange Strings(words) within it's own array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] colors = {"black", "yellow", "red", "blue"};
}
```

How does one flip/move element 3 ("blue") to element 0 ("black") in Java?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any reason on why a temporary variable cannot be used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move element to front of array based on index number in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598225/move-element-to-front-of-array-based-on-index-number-in-java)